# Printer spooler service stop running when sent print job

Tags: windows, printer

Every time i am sending a print job to the printer, i am don't get any response from the printer, and at the printer job list at the status of the job, i see that there was an Error, but it don't give me any clue on what could be the problem.
After some investigation i found that every time that i send the print job to the printer the printer spooler service stops to run, then after a second or two it start again (i think that this behavior is related to the printer spooler settings to rerun it self after it stops).

Things that i have tried so far:

- Remove and Install again the Driver.
- After removing the driver, i have removed the unnecessary registry
  keys according to [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/print-spooler-keeps-crashing-in-windows-7-ultimate/f47b10d6-fba4-412e-bf49-5daaba31c601) article from Microsoft, these are:

  Rename all files and folders in:

  > c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86

  Remove anything but `Drivers Print` and `Processors`:

  > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environment\Windows
  >   NT x86

  Remove anything in here:

  > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors

  but:

  - BJ Language Monitor
  - Local Port
  - Microsoft Document Imaging Writer Monitor
  - Microsoft Shared Fax Monitor
  - Standard TCP/IP Port
  - USB Monitor
  - WSD Port
- Disconnect and Reconnect the Printer.
- Clean the computer from Viruses & Spywares.

Currently i am stuck, i have no more things to try, if anybody know about any kind of solution please let me know about it.

Since i am want to keep this post as general problem that relate to the printer spooler, and not just my particular problem, i didn't included inside the windows version & the printer model, they are (although i think that it isn't relate just for that particular model):

Windows 7 32bit, HP Officejet 4500 G510g-m (connect to the computer via USB).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen Win7's print spooler fail several times usually to do with out of date printer drivers or incorrect versions. You can manage alot of printer settings & information within the 'Print Management' section of Control Panel/Administrative Tools.

There is a drivers section where you can remove old drivers, i would suggest removing anything HP (if possible) and reinstalling the latest version from their [website](http://support.hp.com) :)

There are 3 different [drivers listed for this printer](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4062&lc=en&cc=uk&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3919449#N195), Basic, Enterprise and Full Feature. I would suggest the latter if you havn't got it already...

Comment: Obviously any crashes of the print spooler should be listed in event viewer, do these error messages give you any hints?

Comment: i should check the event viewer, that one i have forgot. But in relation to the drivers i have uninsulated anything relate to HP, and reinstalled the latest driver i could find from HP.

Comment: Are you able to test the printer on a different Win7 32-bit PC? I'm thinking along the lines of something broken within Windows...